# Add User Active Directory with password and compare with AD Password Complexity

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords

I'm trying to use a script to create User account on my AD.(Newbie)

I use this kind of powershell code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Intro
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
Echo "The $date - Adding new user" 

#GET NAME and SURNAME :
$name = Read-Host "Enter the NAME of the user, please ?"
$surname = Read-Host "Enter the SURNAME of the user, please?" 

#Username
$login = ($surname).Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + $name.Substring(0, 2).ToLower() 

#Password requirement
Write-Verbose -Message "The password must contains : 8 char. with 1 maj. , 1 min. et  1 number or 1 char special." -Verbose
$password = Read-Host "Enter the password" 

#Verify login does not exist
Echo "Wait a seconds..."
if (Get-ADUser -Filter { SamAccountName -eq $login }) {   
    Write-Warning "User Already Exist! please Try again..."   
    .\new_user.ps1
} 
else {   
    #User Creation With File Folder
    try {       
        New-ADUser  -Name "$name $surname" -GivenName $name -Surname $surname -SamAccountName $login -UserPrincipalName $login@contonso.com -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force) -PasswordNeverExpires $true -CannotChangePassword $True -Enabled $true -path “OU=User, DC=Contonso, DC=com”       
        Write-Verbose -Message "The user account $login has been created and is active. Send an email with these credential" -Verbose       
    }   
    catch {       
        $_ | Out-File -FilePath C:\LOGS\EU-$login-$date.txt       
        Write-Warning "Sorry. An error as occured creating the user account. Thanks to try again."       
    }   
    try {       
        New-Item -Path \\FILESERVER\D$\Share\4.Users -Name "$login" -ItemType Directory       
        Write-Verbose -Message "The file folder of $login is now available." -Verbose       
    }   
    catch {
        $_ | Out-File -FilePath C:\LOGS\ER-$login-$date.txt       
        Write-Warning "Sorry. An error as occurred while creating the folder, please contact the IT Team.Thanks"       
    }
}
```

If i put example "apple" as a password, the code will continue creating the account with the password but the account is disable and on my log i will have "Password does not fit with Active Directory complexity (set on GPO).

So i know there is a cmd: "Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy" how to use it to compare my password with this ?
I found some function on internet but they use password policy directly on the powershell script.
In my case i want to compare directly with the ADDefaultDomainPassword Policy.

Any Idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To test if a password would pass the complexity rules, you can use below function:

```
function Test-DomainPassword {
    # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Password,

        [string]$SamAccountName = $null,
        [string]$DisplayName = $null
    )
    $PasswordPolicy = Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($Password.Length -lt $PasswordPolicy.MinPasswordLength) {
        Write-Verbose "Password '$Password' is too short. Minimal length is $($PasswordPolicy.MinPasswordLength)"
        return $false
    }
    if (($SamAccountName) -and ($Password -match [regex]::Escape($SamAccountName))) {
        Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' includes the users SamAccountName"
        return $false
    }
    if ($DisplayName) {
        # The displayName is parsed for delimiters: commas, periods, dashes or hyphens, underscores, spaces, pound signs, and tabs.
        # If any of these delimiters are found, the displayName is split and all parsed sections (tokens) are confirmed not to be
        # included in the password.
        # Tokens that are shorter than three characters are ignored, and substrings of the tokens aren't checked.
        $tokens = $DisplayName -split '[-,._ #\t]'
        foreach ($token in $tokens) {
            if (($token) -and ($token.Length -ge 3) -and ($Password -match [regex]::Escape($token))) {
                Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' includes (part of) the users DisplayName"
                return $false
            }
        }
    }
    if ($PasswordPolicy.ComplexityEnabled) {
        # see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb726984(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN
        # chapter 'Passwords Must Meet Complexity Requirements':
        # Passwords must use three of the four available character types:
        # lowercase letters, uppercase letters, numbers, and symbols.

        $failures = @()
        # check for presence of
        # - Uppercase: A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
        if ($Password -cnotmatch "[A-Z\p{Lu}\s]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing Uppercase characters"
        }
        # - Lowercase: a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters
        if ($Password -cnotmatch "[a-z\p{Ll}\s]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing Lowercase characters"
        }
        # - Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
        if ($Password -notmatch "[\d]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing digits (0-9)"
        }
        # - Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/
        if ($Password -notmatch "[^\w]") {
            $failures += "- The password is missing Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;`"'<>,.?/"
        }
        # test if we have more than 1 mismatch (password needs at least 3 out of 4 to be OK)
        if ($failures.Count -gt 1) {
            Write-Verbose "The password '$Password' failed because:`r`n{0}" -f ($failures -join "`r`n")
            return $false
        }
    }

    $true
}
```

Use it like this:

```
# both parameters -SamAccountName and -DisplayName are optional
$displayName = '{0} {1}' -f $firstname, $surname
if (Test-DomainPassword -Password $password -SamAccountName $login -DisplayName $displayName -Verbose) {
    # the password is OK, create the new user here:
    $userParams = @{
        SamAccountName        = $login
        GivenName             = $firstname
        Surname               = $surname
        DisplayName           = $displayName
        UserPrincipalName     = '{0}@contonso.com'-f $login
        AccountPassword       = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -force
        PasswordNeverExpires  = $true
        CannotChangePassword  = $true
        Path                  = 'OU=User,DC=Contonso,DC=com'
        Enabled               = $true
        # etcetera
    }

    New-ADUser @userParams
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User $login NOT created because the password did not pass the test"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why i have to use this function and not "just" compare with AD complexity? Is not possible to use some (i invent) formula like if ($password not equal to GETADDefaultComplexity) do this or this..? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Escambray The function **is** comparing to the default domain complexity rules if the result of `Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy` property `ComplexityEnabled` is true. In that case, one should test the three out of four rules.

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks a lot!! I 'll try and i comeback to you. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have this error: Test-DomainPassword : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Password'.
At C:\Scripts\new_user.ps1:104 char:25
+ if (Test-DomainPassword -Password $password -SamAccountName $login -DisplayName  ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-DomainPassword], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Test-DomainPassword

Comment: @Escambray You may have made a copy/paste error then or incorrectly altered the parameter `$Password` in the function, because for me it works like intended..