# Reset Multiple User Passwords in PowerShell via Text File

Tags: powershell, automation, change-password

I have script that (that I tweaked from a forum) that reads a text file which contains usernames.

This generates a 9 character random password and outputs the password via PowerShell:

```
 $ListOfUsers = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
 foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
     #Generate a 9-character random password
     $Password = -join ((33..126) | Get-Random -Count 9 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })
     #Convert the password to secure string
     $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
     #Reset the account password
     Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset
     #Display userid and password values 
     Write-Host $user, $Password
 }
```

Since the password it displays contains special characters - this cause problems for certain users who access access special pieces of equipment on our network, I am forced to set random password manually in AD for these users.

I was wondering if it is possible to define a random password that contains letters (lower and higher case) and numbers only?

OR

Could I supply a text file with passwords on each line for PowerShell to set for each user?

**UPDATE 1**

@Theo I ran your code and got this error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $ListOfUsers = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
$result = foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
    #Generate a 9-character random password
    $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
    #Convert the password to secure string
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    #Reset the account password
    Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset
    #Display userid and password values 
    #Write-Host $user, $Password

    # or better yet, output the newly set passwords as PsCustomObject to use in a csv file
    [PsCustomObject]@{User = $user; Password = $Password}
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file you can open in Excel by double-clicking it
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewPasswords.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
New-Password : The term 'New-Password' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:17
+     $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-Password:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At line:6 char:36
+     $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
 
Please enter the desired password for 'CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net'
Password:
```

Seem like New-Password is not available on my PowerShell.

Unless you can see something I can't?

**UPDATE 2**

@Theo ran it your script with changes (removed the symbols) got this error message:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> function New-Password {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(8, 128)]
        [int]$TotalLength = 9,
        [int]$LowerAlpha = 3,
        [int]$UpperAlpha = 4,
        [int]$Digits = 2
    )
    # check if the given parameters are => 0 and <= $TotalLength
    $LowerAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($LowerAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $UpperAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($UpperAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $Digits     = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($Digits, $TotalLength))

    if ($TotalLength - ($LowerAlpha + $UpperAlpha + $Digits) -lt 0) {
        throw "Too many alphas, digits or symbols to fit the total password length"
    }
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()

    if ($LowerAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | Get-Random -Count $LowerAlpha)) }
    if ($UpperAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | Get-Random -Count $UpperAlpha)) }
    if ($Digits)     { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random -Count $Digits)) }

    ($list | Sort-Object {Get-Random}) -join ''
}

$ListOfUsers = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
$result = foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
    #Generate a 9-character random password
    $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
    #Convert the password to secure string
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    #Reset the account password
    Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset
    #Display userid and password values 
    #Write-Host $user, $Password

    # or better yet, output the newly set passwords as PsCustomObject to use in a csv file
    [PsCustomObject]@{User = $user; Password = $Password}
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file you can open in Excel by double-clicking it
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewPasswords.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
New-Password : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Symbols'.
At line:31 char:45
+     $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
+                                             ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Password], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-Password
 
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At line:33 char:36
+     $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
 
Please enter the desired password for 'CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net'
Password:
```

I even removed changed this line from this:

```
+     $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
```

To this:

```
+     $Password = New-Password
```

Got this error then:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> function New-Password {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(8, 128)]
        [int]$TotalLength = 9,
        [int]$LowerAlpha = 3,
        [int]$UpperAlpha = 4,
        [int]$Digits = 2
    )
    # check if the given parameters are => 0 and <= $TotalLength
    $LowerAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($LowerAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $UpperAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($UpperAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $Digits     = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($Digits, $TotalLength))

    if ($TotalLength - ($LowerAlpha + $UpperAlpha + $Digits) -lt 0) {
        throw "Too many alphas, digits or symbols to fit the total password length"
    }
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()

    if ($LowerAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | Get-Random -Count $LowerAlpha)) }
    if ($UpperAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | Get-Random -Count $UpperAlpha)) }
    if ($Digits)     { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random -Count $Digits)) }

    ($list | Sort-Object {Get-Random}) -join ''
}

$ListOfUsers = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
$result = foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
    #Generate a 9-character random password
    $Password = New-Password
    #Convert the password to secure string
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    #Reset the account password
    Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset
    #Display userid and password values 
    #Write-Host $user, $Password

    # or better yet, output the newly set passwords as PsCustomObject to use in a csv file
    [PsCustomObject]@{User = $user; Password = $Password}
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file you can open in Excel by double-clicking it
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewPasswords.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Char, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]] does 
not contain a method named 'new'.
At line:19 char:5
+     $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:21 char:24
+     if ($LowerAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:22 char:24
+     if ($UpperAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:23 char:24
+     if ($Digits)     { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string.
At line:33 char:36
+     $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
 
Please enter the desired password for 'CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net'
Password:
```

Seems like the issue is on this line:

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()
```

**UPDATE 3**

I tried all your code without any changes and got this error message:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> function New-Password {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(8, 128)]
        [int]$TotalLength = 10,
        [int]$LowerAlpha = 3,
        [int]$UpperAlpha = 2,
        [int]$Digits = 3,
        [int]$Symbols = 2
    )
    # check if the given parameters are => 0 and <= $TotalLength
    $LowerAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($LowerAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $UpperAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($UpperAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $Digits     = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($Digits, $TotalLength))
    $Symbols    = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($Symbols, $TotalLength))

    if ($TotalLength - ($LowerAlpha + $UpperAlpha + $Digits + $Symbols) -lt 0) {
        throw "Too many alphas, digits or symbols to fit the total password length"
    }
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()
    # older PowerShell versions use: $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[char]

    if ($LowerAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | Get-Random -Count $LowerAlpha)) }
    if ($UpperAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | Get-Random -Count $UpperAlpha)) }
    if ($Digits)     { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random -Count $Digits)) }
    if ($Symbols)    { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?~' | Get-Random -Count $Symbols)) }

    ($list | Sort-Object {Get-Random}) -join ''
}

$ListOfUsers = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
$result = foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
    #Generate a 9-character random password
    $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
    #Convert the password to secure string
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    #Reset the account password
    Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset
    #Display userid and password values 
    #Write-Host $user, $Password

    # or better yet, output the newly set passwords as PsCustomObject to use in a csv file
    [PsCustomObject]@{User = $user; Password = $Password}
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file you can open in Excel by double-clicking it
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewPasswords.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Char, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]] does not contain a method named 'new'.
At line:21 char:5
+     $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:24 char:24
+     if ($LowerAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:25 char:24
+     if ($UpperAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:26 char:24
+     if ($Digits)     { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string.
At line:37 char:36
+     $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
 
Please enter the desired password for 'CN=Test User,CN=Users,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=net'
Password:
```

Comment: If your environment has password complexity rules enabled, you must at least have a combination of digits, upper and lowercase letters. You can test if a password like that would pass with [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73373705/9898643)

Comment: I have checked the policy and only can see 7 characters required for a password nothing else is enforced.

Comment: As I have explained, you need to copy the function `New-Password` to your script as well. Copy that, put it above all other code and then run the script

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Theo I was busy with task but please see my 2nd update above.

Comment: Please copy the function from my answer again. In your edited code it is missing the `Symbols` parameter . About the list declaration, what PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: @Theo Tried all your code without changing (now I realised what I did wrong) and it failed see Update 3, my PS version is 4.0.

Comment: It would help if you would read the code.. I clearly added a comment _older PowerShell versions use: `$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[char]`_. As you seem to have an old version, you need to create the list that way instead.

Comment: @Theo Dude!!!!! You are the man!!!!!!!!! It worked!!! Currently I have a heap of tasks on going so when looking at your code the # part was colour grey it didn't really stick out to me, as I breaking down the rest of the script. We are running server 2012 R2 on our DCs it why it is an older version of PS.

Comment: @Theo Last (dumb question) at the beginning of your script you define the password length, lowercase, highercase, digits and symbols but then further down the script you define the password length and state 0 symbols but couldn't I just make alterations for the new-password function and remove symbols then further down I don't need to define password length again?

Comment: Please see my latest edit. I have posted code with a stripped-down version of the function. Now it only has one optional parameter: `$TotalLength` which defaults to 10, but you can set it to any other value in the range of 8-128. For your convenience I have posted the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below helper function to generate passwords with or without special characters:

```
function New-Password {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(8, 128)]
        [int]$TotalLength = 10,
        [int]$LowerAlpha = 3,
        [int]$UpperAlpha = 2,
        [int]$Digits = 3,
        [int]$Symbols = 2
    )
    # check if the given parameters are => 0 and <= $TotalLength
    $LowerAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($LowerAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $UpperAlpha = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($UpperAlpha, $TotalLength))
    $Digits     = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($Digits, $TotalLength))
    $Symbols    = [math]::Max(0,[math]::Min($Symbols, $TotalLength))

    if ($TotalLength - ($LowerAlpha + $UpperAlpha + $Digits + $Symbols) -lt 0) {
        throw "Too many alphas, digits or symbols to fit the total password length"
    }
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()
    # older PowerShell versions use: $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[char]

    if ($LowerAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | Get-Random -Count $LowerAlpha)) }
    if ($UpperAlpha) { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | Get-Random -Count $UpperAlpha)) }
    if ($Digits)     { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random -Count $Digits)) }
    if ($Symbols)    { $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'!@#$%^&*()_-+=[{]};:<>|./?~' | Get-Random -Count $Symbols)) }

    ($list | Sort-Object {Get-Random}) -join ''
}
```

Usage:

Paste the function above on top of your script and then your code would become:

```
$ListOfUsers = Get-Content C:\temp\list.txt
$result = foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
    #Generate a 9-character random password
    $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0
    #Convert the password to secure string
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    #Reset the account password
    Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset
    #Display userid and password values 
    #Write-Host $user, $Password

    # or better yet, output the newly set passwords as PsCustomObject to use in a csv file
    [PsCustomObject]@{User = $user; Password = $Password}
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file you can open in Excel by double-clicking it
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewPasswords.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

---

As per your comment, here's a stripped-down version of the code, where the `New-Password` function now only has one optional parameter: `$TotalLength`.
It will only use uppercase and lowercase characters plus digits. No more symbols.

```
function New-Password {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateRange(8, 128)]
        [int]$TotalLength = 10
    )
    # calculate the minimum number of characters (lower/upper and digits) needed: 
    # maximum in $TotalLength divided by 3 (rounded up)
    $numChars = [int][math]::Ceiling($TotalLength / 3)

    $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[char]
    # PowerShell versions => 5 use: 
    # $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char]]::new()

    while ($list.Count -lt $TotalLength) {
        # add lower, upper characters and digits to the list
        $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' | Get-Random -Count $numChars))
        $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' | Get-Random -Count $numChars))
        $list.AddRange([char[]]([char[]]'0123456789' | Get-Random -Count $numChars))
    }
    # return the randomized password
    (($list | Sort-Object {Get-Random}) -join '').Substring(0, $TotalLength)
}

$ListOfUsers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\list.txt'
$result = foreach ($user in $ListOfUsers) {
    #Generate a 9-character random password
    $Password = New-Password -TotalLength 9  # if you don't set the TotalLength it will default to 10
    #Convert the password to secure string
    $Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
    #Reset the account password
    Set-ADAccountPassword $user -NewPassword $Pass -Reset

    # output the newly set passwords as PsCustomObject to use in a csv file
    [PsCustomObject]@{User = $user; Password = $Password}
}

# show on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to CSV file you can open in Excel by double-clicking it
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\NewPasswords.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: Apologies for asking stupid questions in advance as I am beginner/idiot to PowerShell. I could alter your helper function to accommodate my password but would the code just follow after ($user in $ListOfUsers) in my code? as I know I will a mistake. Also relating to Usage does that just define total length of password is 9 would that incorporate number 0 only?

Comment: @S.Mahmood just put the function on top of your script and where your code now uses `$Password = -join ((33..126) | Get-Random -Count 9 | ForEach-Object { [char]$_ })`, replace that with `$password = New-Password -TotalLength 9 -Symbols 0`. Parameter `TotalLength` just says how many characters you want it to be. The other parameters determine how many digits, upper and lowercase characters you want minimum. Play around with it, you'll see fast enough how to use it

Comment: @S.Mahmood I have just edited my answer to show you how you can use it in your code. I also made a change in how to display/save the results

Comment: I have tried to run your script but failed.. Please see my Update 1.

Comment: @S.Mahmood You forgot to copy the function `New-Password` that does the work **on top** of the script.. If you don't add that, Powershell cannot know it exists  right?

Comment: Theo me being an idiot I was assume I would run that code separately first then run the other code after it but thanks to pointing that out.